# How to compleately remove the i3 desktop enviroment from Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, desktop-environments

I'm trying to remove the i3 desktop environment from the Ubuntu (14.04) login screen.

after following these commands in root I had i3 installed;

```
# echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(lsb_release -c -s) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install sur5r-keyring
# apt-get update
# apt-get install i3
```

Anyway, when I use I3 and open say; VLC, Firefox & nautilus - I3 will "crash" leaving me with just my desktop and an unresponsive computer. 
(I'm assuming this has something to do with my GPU being AMD and using the proprietary drivers - as I've not had this problem on my laptop which I installed i3 on first and that thing is older than life itself!

So far I've;

- Removed any traces of i3 from **other software**
- Removed any traces of i3 from **Updates**

Also;

```
utuna@utuna:~$ sudo apt-get remove i3; sudo apt-get purge i3; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for utuna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'i3' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'i3' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
utuna@utuna:~$
```

I've seen through Google that there are tutorials on how to remove Lubuntu, Kubuntu etc from Ubuntu, but not i3 and frankly, this is driving me mad!

Sorry if my layout and English is poor, first attempt!

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can do

```
sudo apt remove i3* && sudo apt autoremove
```

to remove all of i3 and anything i3 installed

Comment: It has already mentioned in the question.

Comment: `this worked for me. The i3* unloaded more packages than the ones in the equestion

Comment: In addition to the answer of [a guest trying to help](https://askubuntu.com/a/954854/1744063): Error `no matches found: i3*` will be displayed if not surrounded in quotes.
So instead it will look like this sudo apt remove 'i3*' && sudo apt autoremove

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem today 
Do `sudo apt remove i3-wm and i3-wm-dbg`
Your problem might've been solved by now 
But leaving this here for the people in future 
This is my first answer on this forum

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to look for i3 in the Ubuntu software center and delete it from there.

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged, you can also accept your own answer as it may help others

Comment: Take a look at the guide http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/i/i3-wm/uninstall/index.html