# Switching back to GDM

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, i3-wm

I am running Ubuntu 17.10.

I decided to try the I3 window manager, but do not like it.

Now I can't switch back to Gnome. The login screen does not have a place to select the window manager to use. (It used to).

There is a place to enter my password, and at the top of the screen there is a panel with an accessibility control and WiFi, etc. icons, but no place to choose the window manager.

**UPDATE**

Here is a picture of the login screen. Note that there is no selection "cog" symbol. Sorry for the ugly "screenshot", but without being logged in, I had to use my phone camera.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I uninstalled I3 with this command and rebooted. I am happily back in Gnome.

```
sudo apt remove i3* && sudo apt autoremove
```

(https://askubuntu.com/a/954854/234540)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "cog" symbol on the loging screen. It is next to the login (Anmelden in German) button on my login screen

Comment: There is no "cog" symbol. See the updated question above with an image.